# Will the subclass of an activity bound to the same service if the father class does so?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am working on a service as utility holding bluetooth connection and communication, I think bind an activity to service is more convenient, So my question is: Is that possible for a subclass to bind to same service by default as its parent one?

Comment: Did you try? Does it work?

Comment: @michoprogrammer Sorry I did not, for potential extension of app, I chose to use intent to send messages to activities that my service would like to communicate, while service itself just holds the connection. the only problem is efficiency. I have tested sending intent with  high frequency. So far it works well.